# PHP Lookaround: Get all text until it finds a certain string

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to get the texts until it finds a certain match.

For example:

I want to get all the text before it finds the word `the`

Currently I have this rule `/([[:alnum:]|\s|.]*)(?!the)/ui`

With this text:

`this is completely customizable through the dashboard. This is a separate area from the main c`

The problem is the first group matches the entire line and doesn't stop when the word `the` has been found. What I expect is:

Match 1: `this is completely customizable through`
Match 2: `dashboard. This is a separate area from`

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the [sample](https://regex101.com/r/hK1gL9/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use **lazy matching** with a look-ahead:

```
/.+?(?=\bthe\b)/s
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL4aM2/3), matches are

```
this is completely customizable through 
the dashboard. This is a separate area from
```

The `s` modifier is used to force a `.` to match a newline, too. Lazy matching means it will search for the closest `the` and `\b` help find the whole word `the`, not part of the word `theater`.

Lazy matching as described at [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution):

> The lazy `.*?` guarantees that the quantified dot only matches as many characters as needed for the rest of the pattern to succeed.

Your `([[:alnum:]|\s|.]*)` regex is a bit wrong since `|` inside a character class is treated as a literal pipe symbol. Also, `.` includes `[:alnum:]`, thus, it is redundant. You can write it as `([\s.]*)`, or just `.*` with `/s` (dotall, singleline) modifier. But as it is greedy (i.e. matches as many characters as it can when looking for a match), it will only stop before the final `the`. So, instead of `*` you need to use `*?` - lazy matching.

Since you may not be interested in empty matches, the `*` (0 or more occurrences) should be replaced with `+` (1 or more occurrences of the preceding subpattern).

Here is [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/mE33QG):

```
$re = '/.+?(?=\bthe\b)/s'; 
$str = "this is completely customizable through the dashboard. This is a separate area from the main c"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for adding all the details and the other possible options! Much appreciated.

Comment: I have another follow up question. I needed to get the word `the` in the middle and just ignore the other instances and group the content around the word `the`. Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/hK1gL9/4) However the problem is it doesn't match any unless I add the word `the` before the entire text.

Comment: Something like this: [`(?s)(\b.{0,45})\bthe\b(\b.{0,45})(?=\bthe\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/hK1gL9/5)?

Comment: Damn. It took you just mins to do that for me it took me almost an entire day. Thanks heaps!

Comment: By the way, one last thing. I see a problem with the regex you created. If I add another `the` at the start of the line it does not match anything. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/hK1gL9/5)

Comment: Please elabroate. There is a match, `the` in the middle is "grouped against". Perhaps, you want to just use a lazy version of the limiting quantifier so as to get the first `the`? [`(?s)(\b.{0,45}?)\bthe\b(\b.{0,45})(?=\bthe\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/hK1gL9/7)?

Comment: I think the link did not update. Here it is [again](https://regex101.com/r/hK1gL9/8) I wanted to deselect the first instance of `the` at the beginning and keep the original selection. Which is like [this](http://screencast.com/t/qXVshbUW6WMY). Notice the word `the` getting omitted. Currently it includes the first instance.

Comment: Do you just want to skip `the` at the beginning or just first `the`? This is becoming too vague.Have a look at [`(?s)((?!\bthe)\b.{0,45})\bthe\b(\b.{0,45})(?=\bthe\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/hK1gL9/9).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92276/discussion-between-johnnyq-and-stribizhev).

Answer (score 0):

Use non-greedy with `*?` instead of only `*`.

Like this:

```
.*?(?=the)
```

Compare this
[`.*?(?=the)`](https://regex101.com/r/mK8hA5/1)

with this
[`.*(?=the)`](https://regex101.com/r/mK8hA5/2)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the non-greedy modifier U capitalized

Also - try using just "the" in the second closure

```
/([[:alnum:]|\s|.]*)(the)/Ui
```

Check this out

https://regex101.com/r/cF3iK0/1

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to exclude the word `the`, the best way is to split the string instead of trying to match all until this word:

```
$result = preg_split('~\bthe\b~i', $str);
array_pop($result);
print_r($result);
```

You need to remove the last item with `array_pop` since it is not followed by `the`.

As an aside `(?!...)` means *not followed by* and `(?=...)` means *followed by*.

Comment: That's what I actually thought at first by using `(?!...)` I thought it would limit the search until it finds the string. I got it backwards.